# How To Present A view Controller animated from bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I need a Transparent view controller that will come to screen from bottom. I want to see presenting view controller Transparent. I have written this code to present .

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

RatingPopVC *ratingVc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RatingPopVC1"];


[self.navigationController presentViewController:ratingVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

RateView.m file-

```
 (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];//[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing? Please mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a category of UIViewController on Navigation.

Make a method in category for transparency.
Please follow below written code in `.h file` of category

```
@interface UIViewController (navigation)
    - (void)presentTransparentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion;
@end
```

Go to .M file of category

```
#import "UIViewController+navigation.h"

@implementation UIViewController (navigation)

- (void)presentTransparentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    /*
    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0"))
    {
        [self presentIOS7TransparentController:viewControllerToPresent withCompletion:completion];
    } else {
        viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle =   UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
        [self presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:YES completion:completion];
    }
    */

    // viewControllerToPresent.view.alpha=0.7f;
    viewControllerToPresent.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:YES completion:completion];
}

-(void)presentIOS7TransparentController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent withCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    UIViewController *presentingVC = self;
    UIViewController *root = self;

    while (root.parentViewController) {
        root = root.parentViewController;
    }

    UIModalPresentationStyle originalStyle = root.modalPresentationStyle;
    root.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

    [presentingVC presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:YES completion:^{
        root.modalPresentationStyle = originalStyle;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CATransition

check it out this may help you

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:2];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    SecondView *sObj=[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sObj animated:YES];
    [[sObj.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below line of code

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    RatingPopVC *ratingVc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RatingPopVC1"];
    ratingVc.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];//you can set alpha value or Clear Color
    ratingVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;//add this line of code
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:ratingVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope it helps you..!